# Answer accepted and then Unaccepted... Why?

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Changing the Accepted Answer Frowned Upon?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93969/is-changing-the-accepted-answer-frowned-upon)

Just want to know that, If someone answered a question and it was accepted. then it should be locked for certain interval of time. Why is it unaccepted does code stops working or does technology changes so sudden...

Take it as a question or as a suggestion, the acceptance of an answer should be locked like votes are locked for some time until next edit to the post.

Comment: Why? Why should I be prevented from selecting a better answer if one comes in?

Comment: What if both answers are same and you answered it first OP accepted yours and then accepted the other.

Comment: You actually answered 4 minutes after the first answerer in the question I think you mean. The answerer came over here on Meta and complained about not having his answer accepted even though he was first... I think you'll have to let this one go. It won't happen too often.

Comment: Sure Sir... Why not! Its just an open discussion... :) :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Votes are locked to prevent gaming. You'll only really change your vote if the answer was edited for the worse (or for the better for downvoted posts). And the system lets you do that. Votes are a per-answer basis.

On the other hand, the acceptance tick depends upon other answers as well. If someone improves/writes a competing answer and makes it better than yours, the OP has full right to switch over the checkmark.

The unaccept is done by the OP, there's no fishyness in the code.

Comment: accepted and will not unaccept ;)

Comment: You might change to an upvote if it was edited for the better too.

Comment: @DoubleAA: good point, edited

Answer (score 1):

There is restriction of acceptance change on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) or any other site of Stack Overflow.

What important thing is how much answer is giving you a solution or a useful it is. Sometimes it may be possible that after your acceptance of your answer, some other user answer too and give a more clear view on the same question. In such situation user may change his mind and unaccept the first answer and accept another one.